# How to foreach only certain row in a collection at one time?

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm currently doing a foreach loop for multiple collection which is Pizza, SideOrder, Drink and Gift. I want to check each collection if any of the item in the collection has same ID and DateCreated. I only want to foreach every n row of each collection and then the next row.

Below is my coding (partial only because coding too long)

```
int count = Pizzas.Count + SideOrder.Count + Drink.Count + Gift.Count;

for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
{

  foreach (var o in Pizzas)
  {/*to do something*/ }

  foreach (var o in SideOrder)
  {/*to do something*/ }

  foreach (var o in Drink)
  { /*to do something*/ }

  foreach (var o in Gift)
  { /*to do something*/ }


}
```

What I want is like for j = 1, it should foreach the first row of Pizza, SideOrder etc.. Then j = 2, foreach second row.. and so on.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: *for multiple collection which is Pizza, SideOrder, Drink and Gift.* --> so, a single `foreach` for several collection?

Comment: That's not how foreach works.  Just use a plain old for loop and index.

Comment: @BagusTesa I mean each collection has foreach. I just want to do it one row at a time

Comment: @OldProgrammer Do I have to make Pizzas.ToArray()?

Comment: I think you have to think of a better logic to implement this, May be by creating a Class(let it be `Order`) that having these collections and `orderId` and `orderDAte` as members and use `List<Order>` for processing

Comment: @Farid, *Do I have to make Pizzas.ToArray()?*, yes, that way you can iterate it by using `j`. although i'm not sure what do you need, but un-lucky might have a better clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. You might try to get the Collections index without using foreach

```
for(int j = 1; j < count; j++)
{
    Pizzas[j];
    SideOrder[j];
    Drink[j];
    Gift[j];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's the best solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop ,

```
int i = 1;
    while (i < count)
    {
        Pizzas[j];
        SideOrder[j];
        Drink[j];
        Gift[j];
        i++;
    }
```